# How to change the color of NetBeans cursor?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, netbeans, jdk

I recently tried the Darcula LAF theme for NetBeans 8.2 and uninstalled it. Everything seems fine except the fact that the cursor in the NetBeans has now tured to white, which makes it invisible/extremely difficult to mark in the page. How do I set the color of the cursor to black ???

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think it is a bug, but I have found a work around.
In Tools...Options...Fonts & Colors...Highlighting set the values that you want for "Caret color" and "Caret color (override)". And Accept/Apply. You will see no effect.

Then go to Tools...Options...Editor
If you now go to tab "Code Templates" you can check in the code sample box and see that the cursor appears with the new color.
The trick is to click Apply (doing and undoing any other change) from this tab so the cursor setting will make effect.

I hope that works

Comment: A yet better workaround: set the desired color (Caret color, Caret color (override)), accept and go back to editor. Then press "Insert" key and the "override" cursor will have the new color. Press again "Insert" key and back to the normal cursor with the new color.

Comment: I faced exactly the same problem. Your answer didn't work for me but the approach provided in your comment did.

Comment: Hey, Daniel--@Marti gave an Answer that works (for me, anyway).... You might want to select it as THE Answer. I upvoted your Question, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

with netbeans 15 these didn't work for me, what did is the following actions:

1. go to tools->options->Fonts&Colors->Highlighting
2. select: Curet Color
3. select foreground with specific colour, not 'inheritance'
4. activate: 'Apply' then 'OK'
5. restart the IDE